# How to get value of radio button outside of the ng-repeat scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, radio-button

I'm trying to get value of the radio button when the button is checked.
As you can see it works fine in the first of ng-repeat scope

```
<div ng-controller="myController as vm">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="c in vm.questionbox">
      <label for="ques{{$index}}"><input ng-model="$parent.mode" type="radio" name="question" id="ques{{$index}}" ng-value="{{c.value}}"> {{c.name}}</label>
        <ul ng-show="mode == c.value">
          <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in c.answers">
            <label for="ans{{c.id}}{{$index+1}}"><input ng-model="$parent.result.value" value="{{value}}" type="radio" name="answer{{c.id}}" id="ans{{c.id}}{{$index+1}}"> {{value}}</label>
          </li>
        </ul> 
        <div>currently selected: {{result.value}}</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div>currently selected: {{result.value}}</div>
</div>
```

But I'm also want to get this value after ul tag (outside ng-repeat="c in vm.questionbox"). Please some solutions.

You can see full code at this link: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ovwh4M2COIuqDXaQVU5X?p=preview

Comment: You're using `$parent.result.value` as the model, try using `vm`. Ex: `ng-model="vm.resultValue" ....  <div>currently selected: {{vm.resultValue}}</div>`. It seems to work, you can see that [HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/uzeYBFt1yPmjJSytzjFB?p=preview)

Comment: thx, it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the result of each radiobutton in the list.

```
<li ng-repeat="(key, value) in c.answers">
    <label for="ans{{c.id}}{{$index+1}}"><input ng-model="c.selectedAnswer" value="{{value}}" type="radio" name="answer{{c.id}}" id="ans{{c.id}}{{$index+1}}"> {{value}}</label>
</li>
```

Print the selected results with a simple ng-repeat

```
<div>currently selected: <div ng-repeat="answer in vm.questionbox">{{answer.selectedAnswer}} </div></div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/MCFszBx9fJy6ALCtKrvK?p=preview

Comment: Very nice! This is what I was looking for. Thx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with

```
ng-model="$parent.result.value"
```

Just store the answer value in it's own ng-model, and you can access it outside of the `<ul>`.

Here's a working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/zXvsBkZT0VLevp3sAltS?p=preview